# Array from nested serializer is undefined. REDUX, DRF

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble displaying the data from a nested serializer. I can get and see the data via Redux and see that it is in my props, but when I try to map it to my React component or the local state it says that it is undefined. I have been at this for a while and I am sure it is a minor issue but it is extremely frustrating.

Business Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Business

from django.apps import apps as django_apps
from django.conf import settings


def get_job_model():
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.JOB_MODEL, require_ready=False)


Job = get_job_model()


# Job Serializer
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = "__all__"


class CreateBusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    jobs = None

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['owner', 'geolocation']


class GetBusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    jobs = JobSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        # fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['owner', 'geolocation']

class AllBusiness(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ['business', 'address']
```

Business Page Component (abbreviated):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {businessDetail, getBusiness} from "../../../actions/business";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import store from "../../../store";
import {NOT_HOME} from "../../../actions/types";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";


class BusinessPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        businessSlug: this.props.match.params.businessSlug,
        jobs: this.props.jobs  **placed this here so see it in react dev tools**
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.businessDetail(this.state.businessSlug);
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className='pvt' id='business-page'>
            {this.state.jobs.map(job => (
            <div key={job.id} className="col-md-6 col-lg-12 item">
                <div>
                    <div className="card">
                        <Link to={`/job-page/${job.uuid}`} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>))}
            
        </div>
    );
}
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        business: state.business.business_page,
        jobs: state.business.business_page.jobs,

    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, {businessDetail}
)(BusinessPage);
```

These pictures will show the problem in more detail

[React Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezmOG.jpg)

[Redux Dev Tools showing that it definitely exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRP23.jpg)

[Console log when I try to map it to component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sMGd.jpg)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a lifecycle problem.  Both React and Redux are asynchronous so the data that you want might not exist at the moment where you are trying to access it.

`this.state.jobs` is being set in the constructor so it will store the very first value of `this.props.jobs` that it sees -- before the action in `componentDidMount` gets dispatched.    If the jobs get set in the redux state as a result of this action, those changes will be reflected in the `props` but not in the `state`.

The redux store should be the "single source of truth" so you do not want to duplicate the redux state in your component state.  You don't need any component state based on this snippet.

It's not necessary to pass `jobs` as its own prop since you can access that same variable though `this.props.business.jobs`.  But it's not a problem if you want to keep it separate.

If we think that initial value of the `business` is `undefined` or does not have a property `jobs`, then we need to make sure that we are handling that properly.  One simple solution is to replace `undefined` with an empty array `[]` so that you can call `jobs.map()` without errors.

Some of the many ways to safely access a `jobs` array:

```
const { jobs = [] } = this.props.business || {};
```

```
const jobs = this.props?.business?.jobs || [];
```

Component code:

```
class BusinessPage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // we don't need state because the slug is in the props
    const slug = this.props.match.params.businessSlug;
    this.props.businessDetail(slug);
  }

  render() {
    const jobs = this.props?.business?.jobs || [];
    return (
      <div className="pvt" id="business-page">
        {jobs.map((job) => (
          <div key={job.id} className="col-md-6 col-lg-12 item">
            <div>
              <div className="card">
                <Link to={`/job-page/${job.uuid}`} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        business: state.business.business_page,
    };
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, {businessDetail}
)(BusinessPage);
```

Comment: WOWWW!! You are amazing. That did the trick. So what exactly is happening when using (const jobs = this.props?.business?.jobs || []) ?         Thanks again :)

Comment: It is called optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining  `this.props?.business?.jobs` will either safely access jobs or return `undefined`.  We want an array instead of `undefined` so we add the `|| []` at the end which replaces the `undefined` (or an falsy value) with an empty array `[]`.  "Return this first thing or an empty array" evaluates the first thing and only gets to the "or" if it's false.

Comment: You're the best!